# How to free an int array in c++?

Tags: c++

```
int** allocate(int rows, int cols) {
    int ** mat;
    mat = new int*[rows];
    int *temp = new int[rows*cols];
    for(int i = 0; i<rows; i++) {
        mat[i] = temp + i * cols;
    }
    return mat;
}
int **mat = allocate(5, 5);
```

I want to free the matrix after using. my question is, with using `delete[] mat[0];`, how many bytes will be freed? if I use `delete[] mat[1];` after that, I get a segment error.

Comment: You don't. You should use a `std::vector` and not worry about such things.

Comment: As for the code you show, how many times do you call `new[]`? That's the amount of times you should call `delete[]`. And you need to use the actual pointers returned by the `new[]` operator.

Comment: I also recommend you create a matrix class.

Comment: To add to the above comment, if you switch to a matrix class you can encapsulate a 1d vector and pretend that it is a 2d vector.  This gives you better performance than using a 2d vector since each row of a 2d vector does not need to be contiguous with the other rows.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude perhaps two `std::vector`s, one of `int` and another of `int *`, but you can get away with one

Comment: In order of preference: 1. `std::vector`, 2. `new[]` on a 1D array of size `rows*cols` and use 2D emulation to access, 3. An actual array of pointers to arrays. The reason the last is the worst option is because `new[]` could leave your array data strewn about all over memory, slowing down access considerably. The first two options always have *contiguous* allocations.

Comment: @NathanOliver that does seem to be what they are attempting (although perhaps not within a class)

Comment: Any use of new/delete in current C++ code is something that needs to be reviewed. Are you still learning C++? And if so where from?

Comment: There are two uses of `new[]`, so there should be two `delete[]`s. Inside `mat`, only `mat[0]` is a pointer returned from `new[]` (it is the same as `temp`).

Answer (score 3):

You should `delete[]` every value you get from `new[]`, but the preference is to not use either.

In your example you need to `delete[]` one `int*` and one `int**` because that's what you `new[]`ed. The values you pass to `delete[]` must be equal to the values you got from `new[]`.

It is normal to define a class type to encapsulate the ownership of these arrays, because construction and destruction of an object are guaranteed to be paired. If you do so, you need to take care that you cover all the special member functions: constructors (including copy and move), assignment and destructor should ensure that each `new[]` is paired with exactly one `delete[]` of that value. You can have extra `delete[]`, so long as you pass a null pointer in those cases.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that if you have any allocations *at all* then encapsulating this within a `struct` or `class` that has a proper constructor and destructor (plus *Rule of Three* implications) makes it way easier to use and debug.